# Block installation of Tv apk on handset

Tags: android, android-tv

I have develop the android Tv app and I want to restict the apk installation on handset device
i tried different things such as supports-screens,compatible-screens but not working
can anyone help to solve this problem

Comment: Tried this code in manifets but not working
<!--<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"-->
        <!--android:normalScreens="false"-->
        <!--android:largeScreens="false"-->
        <!--android:xlargeScreens="true"/>-->

Comment: there is no way to block installations of APK. `supports-screens` will only prevent installations from play market

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true" />
```

in your manifest, as a direct child of the root `<manifest>` element.

You can read more about the `<uses-feature>` element in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element).